# Xpath to an element with two different contains text

Tags: html, xpath, robotframework

I have the next HTML and i have this xpath to find the "Show":

```
xpath=//*[@id="Some_id"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text (), "Show")]
```

and it works, but i need to find "Show" of a particular item, in this matter of a "Main" item, so i need smth like this:

```
xpath=//*[@id="Some_id"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text (), "Show")]/preceding-sibling::td[contains(text (), "Main")]
```

but it doesn't work. Thanks

```
<tr class="even">
                    <td title="Main">
                          <a href="Stuff_1"><strong>Main</strong></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      text/html
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Another text
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Some text here
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      No
                    </td>
                    <td>

                          <a href="Stuff_1_a">Show</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this xpath. This will first select a `tr` element which contains the specific `td`  and then select the required `a` tag.

```
"//tr[@class='even' and td[@title='Main']]/a[text()='Show']"
```

**EDIT:** This xpath worked for the OP

```
"//*[@id='Some_id']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[@class='even']/td/a[contains(text (), 'Show')]"
```

Comment: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
Not working, sry, any ideas why ?

Comment: Your answer helped me to come with my own, modified solution, but still, so thanks a lot:
xpath=//*[@id="Some_id"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[@class='even']/td/a[contains(text (), 'Show')]

Comment: @PirreLeSang - The expression is legal, I just checked. Not sure why it didn't work for you but glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to find "Show" that belong to the "Main" row in the table.

Here is what i would do

```
xpath=//td[@title='Main']/following-sibling::td[contains(text(), 'Show')]
```

More on xpath axes: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp